# uploading data to json

Tags: python, json

I have a function that filters documents by certain extensions, filtering is performed , but there is a problem with writing json and passing it to a txt file. json.dump without f. write also doesn't work.
you may be able to help solve this problem, thank you !

```
def get_file_json(self):
    result = []
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    for document in documents:
        extension = document.source_file.name.split('.')[-1]
        print(extension)
        if extension == 'txt' or extension == 'pdf':
            result.append(document.source_file.name)
    if result:
        with open('user_documents.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dump(result, f))
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(f'ОК!'))
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? If possible please edit your original post to include the stack trace error

Comment: write() argument must be str not none...this is an error, but if you only use json.dump, json.dumps or f. write(json. dumps (result)) does not result in the desired result, uploading to json and saving to a txt file

Comment: There's no reason why a plain `json.dump(result, f)` wouldn't work with that code and Python 3. Are you sure you're looking in the right place for that `user_documents.txt`? Do you know where it's being written? (`print(f.name)` will tell you.)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is writing to the file, then attempting to write None into it, as that's the return value of `json.dump`.

Either use

```
json.dump(result, f)  # Dump result to `f`
```

or less preferably

```
f.write(json.dumps(result))  # Generate string of result, write to `f`
```

Comment: They said in their question "json.dump without f. write also doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, thank you all !

```
    def get_file_json(self, documents, filename):
    result = []
    for document in documents:
        extension_docx = document.source_file.name.split('.')[-1]
        if extension_docx == 'docx':
            result.append({"docx": document.source_file.name, "pdf": self.get_pdf_path(document)})
    if result:
        with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(result))
```